# Expresión regular para cambiar números

Tags: r, regex

Tengo los siguientes datos

```
datos <- read.table(text = 'col1
"Casa Verde CA/BBE/565655/15"
"Casa  CA/BBE/2345/15 VERDE"
"Casa Verde _CA/BBE/122281/15_B"
"Casa CA/ABC/1281/2015"
"Casa Azul 5_CA/AAA/1281/2017_B2"
"Casa Verde_5_CA/CCC/12/17"
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**datos:**

```
                            col1
1     Casa Verde CA/BBE/565655/15
2      Casa  CA/BBE/2345/15 VERDE
3  Casa Verde _CA/BBE/122281/15_B
4           Casa CA/ABC/1281/2015
5 Casa Azul 5_CA/AAA/1281/2017_B2
6       Casa Verde_5_CA/CCC/12/17
```

Los últimos números es el año. Quiero que si pone 15 se cambie por 2015.

La estructura a buscar es:

2 ó más letras/3 letras/ 2 ó más números /dos números

y cambiar los /dos números por 20 dos números (15 -> 2015)

Lo que haya delante o detrás de la estructura a buscar se puede borrar.
Quedaría algo como esto:

```
1     Casa Verde CA/BBE/565655/15     CA/BBE/565655/2015
2      Casa  CA/BBE/2345/15 VERDE     CA/BBE/2345/2015
3  Casa Verde _CA/BBE/122281/15_B     CA/BBE/122281/2015
4           Casa CA/ABC/1281/2015     CA/ABC/1281/2015
5 Casa Azul 5_CA/AAA/1281/2017_B2     CA/AAA/1281/2017
6       Casa Verde_5_CA/CCC/12/17     CA/CCC/12/2017
```

He probado con

```
 datos$col2 <- stringr::str_replace(datos$col1,"(\\w{2}\\/\\w{3}\\/\\d{2,}\\/)(\\d{2})","\\120\\2")
```

Pero 2015 se convierte en 202015.

Si pruebo con $

```
datos$col2 <- stringr::str_replace(datos$col1,"(\\w{2}\\/\\w{3}\\/\\d{2,}\\/)(\\d{2}$)","\\120\\2")
```

Los que tienen algo detrás del año no cambian.
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Creo que yo no usaría expresiones regulares. Probablemente usaría métodos de manipulación de cadena, como `str_pad`, el cual aplicaría 2 veces sobre el valor que te interesa, la primera vez para añadir '0' como dígito `pad` al inicio, para 3 caracteres y la segunda vez para agregar el dígito '2' como `pad` al inicio para 4 caracteres. Pero, poco he trabajado con R y no puedo darte un ejemplo funcional, tal vez alguien con más experiencia pueda desarrollar mi idea. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el año ocurre siempre en la última cadena, considerando como separador la barra `/`, yo trabajaría solo con esa porción más pequeña de la cadena, es posible que de esta forma sea más simple y seguro aplicar expresiones regulares.

Solo con esta porción de datos, si asumimos que 4 números seguidos es el año y que 2 sería lo mismo pero comenzando del 2000, podríamos hacer algo así:

```
# Recuperamos solo la columna dónde aparece el año
años <- sapply(strsplit(datos$col1, '/'), `[[`, 4)

# Primero procesamos los años de 4 dígitos y luego los de 2
# Dejamos solo los números
años_normalizados <- gsub('.*(\\d{4}).*', '\\1', años)
años_normalizados <- gsub('.*(\\d{2}).*', '20\\1', años_normalizados)

# Hacemos el reemplazo en la columna original
sapply(1:nrow(datos), FUN = function(i) {gsub(años[i], 
                                              años_normalizados[i], 
                                              datos$col1[i])
  })


[1] "Casa Verde CA/BBE/565655/2015" 
[2] "Casa  CA/BBE/2345/2015"        
[3] "Casa Verde _CA/BBE/122281/2015"
[4] "Casa CA/ABC/1281/2015"         
[5] "Casa Azul 5_CA/AAA/1281/2017"  
[6] "Casa Verde_5_CA/CCC/12/2017"
```

Answer (score 1):

aviso: nunca he programado en R.

Regex de busqueda:

```
(.*)(?<firstSection>\w{2}\/\w{3}\/\d{2,}\/)(?<twodigitsyear>\d{2})(?!\d{2})(.*)$
```

Regex de remplazo:

```
$1${firstSection}20${twodigitsyear}$4
```

Resultado:

```
                            col1
     Casa Verde CA/BBE/565655/2015
      Casa  CA/BBE/2345/2015 VERDE
  Casa Verde _CA/BBE/122281/2015_B
           Casa CA/ABC/1281/2015
 Casa Azul 5_CA/AAA/1281/2017_B2
       Casa Verde_5_CA/CCC/12/2017
```

Como veras estoy usando grupos de captura nombrados para hacer mas evidente que el 20 no forma parte de tus grupos de captura.
Agregue ademas un grupo de no captura que basicamente indica que el grupo que sigue no debe estar, para que ignore las expresiones con anhios de 4 digitos.
Finalmente agregamos el terminador de linea $ para asegurarnos que falle antes de intentar coincidencias inneccesarias con el resto del texto.

Entiendo que el codigo final deberia quedar algo como:

```
pattern = '(.*)(?\\w{2}\\/\\w{3}\\/\\d{2,}\\/)(?\\d{2})(?!\\d{2})(.*)$'

# A character vector to search for pattern in
input = ''

# If doing substitution, instances of the pattern
# that are found will be replaced with this:
replacement = '$1${firstSection}20${twodigitsyear}$4'

# Find pattern and replace it
replaced = gsub(
  pattern = pattern,
  replacement = replacement,
  x = input,
  ignore.case = TRUE,
  perl = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Me da un error al meterlo en R, pero se capta la idea. Gracias!!